# Get Name of directory within DirectoryInfo in DataBinding in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, directoryinfo

I need get the **Name** of **subfolder** in **asp BoundField** in c# using **DataBinding**

For know the **Name** of **subfolder** I have used the **DirectoryInfo**

In the coding I have this error :

> A field or property with the name 'Name' was not found on the selected
>   data source

My code below.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

**.cs**

```
using (DataSet ds =
    new DataSet())
{
    DataTable dt =
        new DataTable();

    sda.Fill(ds);
    sda.Fill(dt);

    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    string FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/myfolder/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sFolder"].ToString().Replace('/', '\\'));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(FilePath + "<br /><br />");

    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@FilePath);
    DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirectories)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(dirInfo.Name + "<br />");                                              

    return dt;
}
```

**.aspx**

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                    CssClass="mGrid" Width="500" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Folder name" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/merging-multiple-datatables-into-single-datatable-using-asp/)

**Merging Multiple DataTables Into Single DataTable Using ASP.Net C#**